# Find sublines, given initial and final offsets, via the command line

Tags: line, ogr, linear-referencing, length, command-line

I have a CSV file that looks essentially like this:

```
id,id_wkt,start,end,wkt
11,11,0,43,"LINESTRING(3.3623676 51.3132714,3.3626663 51.3130068,3.363068 51.3126811,3.3636323 51.3122504,3.3640754 51.3119614,3.3643705 51.3117777)"
12,11,43,217,"LINESTRING(3.3623676 51.3132714,3.3626663 51.3130068,3.363068 51.3126811,3.3636323 51.3122504,3.3640754 51.3119614,3.3643705 51.3117777)"
```

It consists of records with a WKT linestring. Some of the WKTs appear multiple times and the actual geometry has to be obtained from the linestring using the start and end offsets (length in metres along the line) in their respective columns.

I would like to extract sublinestrings based on these length offsets. Is this possible via a command line tool like OGR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I have indeed found a solution, using `ogr2ogr`:

```
ogr2ogr output.csv -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT input.csv -dialect SQLITE -sql "SELECT id, id_wkt, ST_Line_Substring(GEOMETRY, start / GeodesicLength(GEOMETRY), end / GeodesicLength(GEOMETRY)) FROM input"
```

It gives

```
WKT,id,id_wkt
"LINESTRING (3.3623676 51.3132714,3.3626663 51.3130068,3.36274075608485 51.3129464307024)","11","11"
"LINESTRING (3.36274075608485 51.3129464307024,3.363068 51.3126811,3.3636323 51.3122504,3.3640754 51.3119614,3.36436609040842 51.3117804449745)","12","11"
```

Comment: I wonder if `GeodesicLength(GEOMETRY)` is evaluated both times, which would impact performance. In that case, would there be an alternative that isn't too complicated?